# Can't get banner under top nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Having issues getting my homepage banner up under the top nav like the client wants. I cannot modify the html too much, as I'm using a Sitefinity master template for the header/footer, and another template that inherits it for the homepage. It appears to work ok for me in Chrome, but not FF/IE. I've tried a negative bottom margin on the nav, and the negative top margin on the banner, among other things. If i try another over -50, the banner gets shoved to the right of the nav. What am I missing??

```
/* Top Nav */
#NavWrapper {
    /*margin-bottom:-50px;*/
    position:relative;
}
.navbar-default {
    background:none;
    border-color:transparent;
}

/* Homepage */
.home-banner{
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bc5057b0/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zeh23wyp/1/ -- scroll down in the css pane. This is a desktop solution, when the nav goes under the logo, the image needs swapping. This is a poor way of designing this type of design pattern.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zeh23wyp/1/